# Is there a way to rotate an object based on players position in unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a basic platformer using Unity and my player has a sort of gun. My bullet is only shooting in one location, and I would like it to rotate with the player. I am quite new to C# and need some help.

I have tried using if and else statements and I have tried manually rotating it.

My code:

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class fire : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Transform player;

        public Rigidbody2D rb2d;

        public Transform enemy;

        public Transform myspawn;

        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {

        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Spawn"))
            {
                transform.position = player.position;
                rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(10.0f, 0.0f);

            }

        }
        private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
        {
            if(collision.transform == enemy)
            {
                transform.position = myspawn.position;
            }

        }
    }
```

I expect the output to rotate the bullet with the player, and using the if statements I got a lot of different errors. The actual output I got was the bullet just wouldn't move until you manually push the bullet.

Comment: Could you show your code for `I have tried using if and else statements`? Currently I don't see where something is ment to be rotated in your code... Or/And tell us what the errors say?

Comment: I have never ever made a 2d project but i think this might will work for you: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your gun is only shooting at one direction you can do something like this:

Create a new boolean variable, call it something like `isLookingRight` in your player controller script and set it to true if your player is initially looking at right. Whenever player moves left, change this variable to false and change your `Update` in the code you have provided to this:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Spawn"))
    {
        transform.position = player.position;
        if(playerScript.isLookingRight){
            rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(10.0f, 0.0f);
        }
        else{
            rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(-10.0f, 0.0f);  
        }
}
```

What this code does is pretty simple, if your player is looking left, it just changes the velocity to the opposite of what it would normally be. But you need to be changing the `isLookingRight` correctly in your player movement script.